"Signing" Error on Debian 11 when I try to install MySQL Server
For adding a repository on apt in Debian 11, I did this,
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.22-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.22-1_all.deb

But, when I continue, doing the following step,
sudo apt update

I obtain this result,

Err:4 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian bullseye InRelease The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B7B3B788A8D3785C

And when after that, I make,
sudo apt-get install mysql-server

Consequently I get,

Package mysql-server is not available, but is referred to by another
package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
obsoleted, or is only available from another source

Well, supposing I get this because I SECURED my computer with the "virtualization" protection option in my BIOS...), my question is how to "sign" the MySQL repository in Debian 11 to get permission for activating ""SECURELY"" this repo, and I could continue installing Ok my MySQL Server on my Debian 11...

You need to import the key

Also installing this should add the correct repository with the key.

Thank you very much, ChaganAuto.
Package mysql-apt-config_0.8.32-1_all.deb WORKED!! for me,
:)
